# npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

When Jenkins tries to run `npm install` on the master node, it returns an error:

> npm: command not found

When I do `npm --version` on the master node it returns the correct version.

Not sure why jenkins is unable to access npm on the master node. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Presumably Jenkins has a different PATH to you. Have you tried using absolute paths instead?

Comment: Are you using Jenkins in Master slave mode?

Comment: Do you have a unix environment ? `sudo - i -u sjenkins` to connect as the user *sjenkins* but use the name that you used. try this command `which npm` as your current user to get the PATH used, you will have something like $PATH_USED/npm. As the jenkins user, do `echo $PATH` take a look if the path exist and if jenkins user has all the right to execute it.